# Getting error when using command line for SASS to watch files

Tags: macos, command-line, sass

I've been having problems getting Sass working from terminal in Mac OS X Mavericks on my Macbook Pro. I'm working off a brand new clean install; reformatted my hard disk, loaded Mavericks, and first thing I went into the command line to set this up.

I did `sudo gem install sass`, then created two files on my desktop, test.css and test.scss. Then, when I try watching the files, I get an error:

```
$ sass --watch desktop/test.scss:desktop/test.css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rb-fsevent
  Use --trace for backtrace.
$
```

I have no idea what's going on or how to fix this, tried searching but didn't find any answers related to my problem. `Sass -v` gives me `Sass 3.3.2 (Maptastic Maple)`.

Comment: there is a screencast about a similar 'watcher' called 'guard'. It describes installing it completely. it comes with a 'sass' watcher and uses the 'rb-fsevent' stuff. [tutorials/guard-is-your-best-friend](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guard-is-your-best-friend--net-31021). May be worth a watch. It is only a few minutes of your time.

Comment: Will give that a watch. This was referencing my machine at the office, and I'm out for the weekend, but I'll give that a go first thing Monday morning. I just discovered this too:
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/running-installing-sass-osx-10-9-mavericks/
which references rb-fsevent. It seems installing sass on Mavericks is a tad different than usual (at least, as far as I can remember). Thanks for the link!

Comment: So, can someone explain the downvote on my original post?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Install the missing file: `gem install rb-fsevent`

The gem uses OS X's FSEvents API to listen for file system events including updated files (for example, your updated Sass file). As your OS has changed, it is reasonable to expect changes to how file system events are handled and therefore any gems that depend on file system behaviour.